# How does YouTube provide video annotations for HTML 5?

Tags: html, video, annotations

I am curious as how to provide annotations to a video using HTML 5. I was wondering if anyone knew how YouTube or another site that uses HTML 5 to play videos knows of a script or package?

Information on support of HTML5 on YouTube video playback:

> http://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: it's all HTML, Javascript and CSS creating the annotations layer over the video, isn't it?

Comment: According to the article, "Video annotations are not supported in the HTML5 video player."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the article provided by @thephpdeveloper Youtube does not support annotations on their HTML5 video player.

Comment: Looks like this has changed recently - example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZT6YpCsapg&html5=1

Answer (score 0):

The approach I am using is to check every few milliseconds (e.g. 200ms), whether an annotation with its start and end time should be activated or not.

```
for(a in annotations){
 if( playbackTime < a.end AND playbackTime >= a.start){
  a.activate()
 }else{
  a.deactivate()
 }
}
```